# Why do you write setter and getter with double t

Tags: suffixes

If you care, setter (plural: setters) and getter (plural: getters) are parts of a computer programms that get (or retrieve) and set (or store) values in memory.

But why do you write that words, that are, anyway, rather artificial (do they have uses in other contexts?) with double t?

You don't do it with other words such as producer, consumer. Even words that finish in consonant (reader) or in t (eater) are just added the r or er suffix.

Please clarify this non important issue to me.

Comment: you can find getter in **go-getter** - an aggressively enterprising person, and **setter is a type of dog**. You can find other nouns that come from verbs using a "tt", like a **putter** - a golf club designed for use in putting, typically with a flat-faced mallet-like head. It really depends on the verb. It works for other letters aswell, like a **runner**

Comment: The why's of English spelling are rather imponderable, however, the answer why is that that is the way it is pronounced with both syllables closed. However, ironically, where I grew up in Glasgow the"tt" was pronounced as a glottal stop: ge'er and se'er, meaning that both t's, by that pronunciation scheme, are redundant.

Comment: @FraserOrr They aren't redundant, they tell you to make a glottal stop! (Cumbernauld girl here) I was so reprimanded by my lancastrian parents for this practice that I still mentally pronounce 'butter' as 'bu-tutut-er'.

Answer (score 1):

A very common word "better" (which can be a noun as well as an adjective, adverb and verb) follows the same pattern.

Conversely "Peter" (name) and "peter" (verb as in "peter out") are pronounced differently.  Under this pattern, "*beter" would then be a homophone for "beater" (also "*seter" & "seater").  The vast majority of words ending "--eter" have the long-e pronunciation, as they end "--meter" (though there are plenty of exceptions such as "perimeter" which can probably be attributed to stress patterns.

"Deter" is different again in pronunciation.

So with a single "t", the pronunciation is ambiguous -- not handy if you've just coined a new word/usage and want to use it in discussions where it should much the source verb ("set"/"get").

In other words, a native speaker's intinct would be to spell it this way.

Note that in your counter-examples, the penultimate syllable is a long vowel sound, whether or not the verb fom which the noun is formed ends "-e".

(This is all based on the accents of southern England)